# MinGW C Compiler Cannot Create Executables when building SDL_Net for DOSBox

Tags: windows, mingw, sdl, dosbox

So I'm trying to build DOSBox with [these instructions](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Building_DOSBox_with_MinGW), and I can't seem to get the networking part to work. I always get to the `./configure --prefix=/mingw` part, but I always get [this error](http://pastebin.com/Q2gtWh25). I've tried adding C:\MinGW\bin to the Path, but it doesn't seem to be working. I don't really know what to do. There's got to be a different answer, but I've pretty much just been using the VS 2015 Command line tools for my time on Windows as I usually do C++ on Linux, so I'm unfamiliar with how it works.

P.S. I know that you can build it with Visual Studio, but I'm building it this way to become more familiar with MinGW.

Comment: please include error in post, not as image

Comment: It should link to a pastebin. The error log was too long to fit into the post, so I put it there.

Comment: sorry, but my firewall prevents me from seeing your error. At least provide the most significant part as text directly in the question.

Comment: It said that: `Checking for c compiler default output file name... configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables See config.log for more details.` I pastebined the config.log file.

Comment: Also if you can't see the instructions I was following, just type into Bing, "building dosbox with mingw" and click on the first link.